# getting client to automatically send data to server

Tags: javascript, ping, server-side

i am running a server side application which receives data of ping done from client side to certain ip addresses.
Currently a person goes to these clients and does the ping manually.
Can i automate this process of client running the ping program through javascript or any client side language ?

I want to make the client automatically ping a few ip addresses, then extract the data from the ping request and then feed this data to the server so it can be recorded.
Is this possible ?

Comment: Do you literally mean `ping`? That's not going to be possible, but making *some* request will be. What kind of data would you need coming back from the request? The servers you are pinging are not under your control?

Comment: @Pekka the server is under my control, i provide services to organisations where i check if their websites are properly available to the public. I have people who go to random customers houses and ping these websites and then report the data.

Comment: @PEkka the problem is i want to run a screipt which makes the clients machine send a ping request to these sites and the latency and package loss needs to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to run a screipt which makes the clients machine send a ping request to these sites and the latency and package loss needs to be reported.

I don't think you can get hold of such low-level information from within Javascript.

What you could do is speed tests in the style of http://speedtest.net, which send data back and forth using JS or Flas. However, I expect a proper speed test is not trivial to implement. I think there are providers who re-sell their ready-made speed testing solutions if that's an option.

Other than that, depending on your situation, maybe consider writing an executable program that calls the system's `ping` command and transmits the results to you. That would require client-side installation though, of course.