# ping cross domain url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, ping

Is there any way that I can ping sites like `http://google.com` (without them providing any pining interface) using only JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to 'ping' from a browser using Javascript. There are some hacks available that allow you to do something similar under specific conditions.

You can find some information here at stackoverflow:

[How to ping IP addresses using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954741/how-to-ping-ip-addresses-using-javascript)
[Is it possible to ping a server from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript)