# ICMP in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, udp, icmp

Is it possible to use icmp in javascript? Is there another accurate way to determinate the ping? What would be the alternative if it isn't possible in javascript, I don't believe java or flash are good alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954741/how-to-ping-ip-addresses-using-javascript TL;DR: No. You need a server-side app.

Comment: no because i want to ping from the client to the server.

Comment: You asked if it was possible; it's not, and I was simply offering one other way that hadn't ruled out already.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OS/native socket level feature that's outside the scope of most Javascript engines. You would need to write something like a browser plugin (which every client would need and would probably have a native component to it).

A Java applet might be possible but I don't know enough on that to comment, that has it's own sandbox rules.