# Javascript: Check the URL is working / existed / reachable (returning Status 200 / non-broken) or not

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404

With Javascript, i want to check a URL is reachable (existed, returning with HTTP Status 200, NOT 404, etc).

Let's say, how to know (by using JS) that:

- "https://www.google.com" (WebSite) .. is a reachable link.
- And, "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" (JS File) .. is also a reachable link.
- And, "https://www.microsoft.com/library/errorpages/Images/Microsoft_logo.png" (Image) also is reachable.

(They are NOT: broken, non-existed, 404, etc).

---

Again how to know, such:

- "http://www.asderafsdfefrasdfsdfasf.com"
- Or, "https://www.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.js" ..

are **BROKEN, not-reachable, non-existed, 404**, etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954741/how-to-ping-ip-addresses-using-javascript

Comment: Did you ever tried with  PHP ?

Comment: @Nikz I think i said "Javascript" above.